# How can i create the tabs in wix custom dialog?

Tags: tabs, wix, customdialog

I am trying to create multiple tabs in wix custom dialog. But i didn't find any example on that. Please provide a solution for creating multiple tabs in custom dialog ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no Tab control in Windows Installer UI. You'll have to either deal with existing (very limited) UI in Windows Installer, or add a bootstrapper and move the desired UI there - it is possible to even create WPF screens.

Answer (score 0):

Tabs are not available in MSI installer therefore WiX does not have them either. The installer UI is very simple and limited. The UI is limited to simple screens and dialog boxes.